# mongodb query month from timestamp

Tags: mongodb

So I am trying to run a few queries and need to put them in Month group.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f1021f15b43e19dabb13a81"},"artist":"Isaac Larson","song":"Network Protocol","station":"PERTHRadio","timeplay":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1594896360000"}},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"},"history":["8609f491-97e7-4862-a848-3712aeb2117e","3f102559-307a-45a5-a9fc-eaa84e0ed491"]}
```

(note picture is of the query above unsure why timeplay has copied from the database that way.

[image: mongodb screenshot]

I have tried to use the documentation provided here  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/

To fetch the month. However I'm having issues saying my query is wrong.

`{$month:{'timeplay': new Date("Jul 16, 2020")}}`
The error

`The provided parameters were invalid. Check your query and try again.`

Comment: month:{$month:"$timeplay"} in projection, you should be able to start from there

Comment: I was able to get it to work